# Output of pandas groupby with cumprod not showing groupby columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand the difference between a mean,sum function vs a cumprod function.
When I run a groupby and then the mean, I get the id column and a mean of the values as expected. [image]

When I run it with cumprod though, there is no groupby column.  How do I ensure that I can get the columns I am grouping by 
[image]

```
x = [.25,.23,.55,.89,-.90,-.04]
id = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
df.groupby('id').mean()
df.groupby('id').cumprod()
```

Comment: `id = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']` - This is a _truly_ horrible idea. Never call your variables `id`, because `id()` is a built-in function.

Answer (score 9):

`df.groupby('id').mean()` is shorthand for `df.groupby('id').agg('mean')`.

`df.groupby('id').cumprod()` is shorthand for `df.groupby('id').transform('cumprod')`.

The key difference here is that the former is a `groupby/agg` operation, while the latter is a `groupby/transform` operation.

`groupby/agg` aggregates each group into a single value. Therefore, the `groupby/agg` operation can return a Series whose index contains groupby keys (in this case, `id` values).

`groupby/transform` operations return a Series with the same number rows as the
original DataFrame, `df`. (`cumprod` is short for cumulative product. Since it returns
a running total of the products, there is one value for each row). Since there is a value for each row of the
original DataFrame, naturally the index can not be the groupby keys. It has to remain
being the index of the original DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

The reason lies in what functions mean() and cumprod() are meant to do.
Mean: "Return the mean of the values for the requested axis"
Cumprod: "Return cumulative product over requested axis"

So mean is meant to return one value for the given axis while cumprod will find the product of the values cumulatively.

If you want to compare whether its working or not, you can compare

```
df.x.cumprod()

0    0.250000
1    0.057500
2    0.031625
3    0.028146
4   -0.025332
5    0.001013
```

vs

```
df.groupby('index').x.cumprod()

0    0.250000
1    0.057500
2    0.031625
3    0.890000
4   -0.801000
5    0.032040
```

The grouped outcome changes from index 3 representing index = 'b'

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `mean()`, `cumprod()` (which converts a series into a single number) is not an aggregator and converts a series into another series. The number and order of rows in the original dataframe is the same as in the `cumprod()` result. You can merge the results into the original dataframe and have access to the values of `id`:

```
df['x_cumprod'] = df.groupby('id').cumprod()
#  id     x  x_cumprod
#0  a  0.25    0.25000
#1  a  0.23    0.05750
#2  a  0.55    0.55000
#3  b  0.89    0.48950
#4  b -0.90   -0.44055
#5  b -0.04   -0.00230
```